# Automatic patch from original repository to fork

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Please, help me!

I have one repo with original source. (Base project) and many forks.

How i can automatic moves bugfix from forks to base project ?

I use bitbucket.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the desired branch and then merge it into it your local branch.

```
# checkout the desired branch to which you want to merge the code into
git checkout <main branch>

# update the local repo with all the code from the remote
git fetch --all --prune

# merge side branch to the main branch
git pull origin <main branch>

# Merge the side branch
git merge <side branch>
```

---

***`Example:`***

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all --prune
git pull origin master
git merge side_branch
```